# Wrong timezone in Laravel 7 after date serialization

Tags: php, php-carbon, laravel-7

I'm working on a new Laravel 7.1 app (Not an upgrade)
But it seems that working with dates serialization loose the timezone.

**config/app.php**

```php
'timezone' => 'Europe/Zurich',
```

**tinker example**

```
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2020-06-22')->timezone
=> Carbon\CarbonTimeZone {#3251
     timezone: Europe/Zurich (+01:00),
   }
```

**[Laravel 7 uses toJson()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)**

```
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2020-06-22')->toJson()
=> "2020-06-21T22:00:00.000000Z"
```

So, when I parse the date back, I'm not getting the proper date.

```
>>> new \Carbon\Carbon('2020-06-21T22:00:00.000000Z')
=> Carbon\Carbon @1592776800 {#3266
     date: 2020-06-21 22:00:00.0 +00:00,
     timezone: "Z",
   }

>>> (new \Carbon\Carbon('2020-06-21T22:00:00.000000Z'))->format('Y-m-d')
=> "2020-06-21"
```

---

Currently I'm doing it like this

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2020-06-21T22:00:00.000000Z')
    ->setTimezone(config('app.timezone'));
```

As alternative I can change the default date format in my models, as stated in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)

```
/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->toIso8601String(); // 2019-02-01T03:45:27+00:00
}
```

But it would be preferable that `Carbon::parse()` and/or `new Carbon()` take my timezone by default, I guess.-

Comment: I see the same issue.

Answer (score 17):

Same problem here.

When upgrading from Laravel 6 -> 7, this was changed. (see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization))
When serializing, the time is updated from local time to UTC (as per ISO-8601).
But when returning the same sting back to php, the Carbon object does NOT use the ISO-8601 timezone representation.

### Problem 1:

When updating to the database, this date is moved with your timezone settings every time.

### Problem 2:

When showing the timestamp in the browser, every representation of this field has to be fixed with the (browsers) timezone settings.

### Fix:

The upgrade manual proposes a [fix](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization).
We use a trait in all our models, so we updated there:

> If you would like to keep using the previous behavior you can override
> the serializeDate method on your model:
>
> ```
> use DateTimeInterface;
>
> /**
>  * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
>  *
>  * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
>  * @return string
>  */
> protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
> {
>     return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
> }
> ```

It would of course be better to use UTC for everything, but that would require the read-back from JSON (ajax) would utilize the same Timezone settings/differences as the serialization.

Comment: The proposed fix only works with eloquent models tho. What about DTOs etc.? I'm baffled that there's no way to configure this globally.

Comment: @Anticom You can use Carbon::serializeUsing() it will change it globally