# How to get time in particular timezone in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I am unable to get the time for a particular timezone using Laravel 8. I have tried the following:

```
Carbon::now(new \DateTimeZone('Indian/Mauritius'))
```

I have also tried to modify the `timezone` in file `config\app.php` as follows:

```
'timezone' => 'Indian/Mauritius'
```

It is always returning me the `UTC` time. How to get the time using Carbon in that specific timezone?

Edits: issue solved, the problem was because of a serialization issue, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649769/wrong-timezone-in-laravel-7-after-date-serialization#)

Comment: After update the config\app.php run these commands , 
--> php artisan config:cache
-->php artisan cache:clear

Comment: have you  tried this Carbon::now()->timezone("Indian/Mauritius");? or as PSA suggested

Comment: @PSA, i tried this, does not work

Comment: @JohnLobo, nopes, it doesn't work. I'm getting `"2021-07-13T11:14:39.845698Z"` while it's 15:15 in Mauritius

Comment: Did you try setting `date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Mauritius');` in the boot method of your AppServiceProvider?

Comment: something doesn't add up, since that first `Carbon::now('Indian/Mauritius')` (or use the object as a param) should definitely work

Comment: @Flame, yes, does it have anything to do with server time configuration?

Comment: @Aless55, no success, i tried this

Comment: @Noor try dd(date_default_timezone_get()) what you get

Comment: @JohnLobo, I get this: "Europe/London"

Comment: Json default output is UTC but you can explicitly call format() or any string formatter to get string with the current timezone of the instance.

Comment: I also think this timezone name is not valid sounds the abbreviation MUT is what you want.

Comment: it could have something to do with your php.ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$dateNow = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$dateNow->setTimezone('Indian/Mauritius');
```

Comment: What do you mean? $dateNow has no value after running?

Comment: no, ypur code is returning me `2021-07-13T12:32:11.585651Z` while it's 16:32 in Mauritius

Comment: I have tested my code, inspecting the $dateNow variable after setTimezone() and the value is correct. I'm pretty sure you mean the data value in the JSON response (which you don't mention) and the problem is in serialization. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649769/wrong-timezone-in-laravel-7-after-date-serialization#

Comment: you can check this by simply doing this: $dateNow = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->setTimezone('Indian/Mauritius')->toDateTimeString();

Comment: you are right, never even thought about the serialization issue

Comment: do you have any idea where the configuration in config/app.php isn't working

Comment: Yes, it should works. If you have set it up, your default Carbon object datetime should be the local hour in Mauritius (not in serialized data)